# How do I get Ubuntu's on-screen keyboard to appear whenever I click on any input field on any program?

Tags: 23.04, accessibility, onscreen-keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 and I have the on-screen keyboard enabled.

While it pops up when I click on the terminal window or other ubuntu/system related programs, it doesn't do the same for Firefox (ex: if I click on the url bar, the keyboard doesn't pop up).

I was able to get the on-screen keyboard to work exactly how I wanted it to on a previous installation of 23.04 by accident. I was trying to install the Florence on-screen keyboard which led me to installing its dependencies but I wasn't able to install Florence itself. Fortunately, the dependencies changed the behavior of Ubuntu's on-screen keyboard and it popped up every time I clicked on any input field on any program. Unfortunately, I cannot find the website that gave instructions on which dependencies to install.

Comment: Try Xorg, disable Wayland.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka before I start disabling stuff, can you tell me why using Xorg will remedy the issue?

Comment: It just costs one restart. Try something reasonable is a way to get close to the answer.